# Difference between HTML and innerHTML

Tags: html

I am new to web designing, please help me with the difference between HTML and innerHTML with example. I have explored for the same but dint find the exact difference between both. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

innerHtml is the html inside a parent element, but not including the parent.

ex:

```
<div>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

The span is the innerHTML of the div whereas the entire block is HTML

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `html()` execute script while
If you set `innerHTML` property scripts are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInnerHTML()
  {
  alert(document.getElementById("tr1").innerHTML);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr id="tr1">
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr id="tr2">
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="getInnerHTML()" value="Alert innerHTML of table row" />
```

the innerHTML is set or get the the HTML of the begin tag to the end of the tag

the example just return :

```
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
```